# How to import variables from one file to another in python

Tags: python, import

Hi I want to try to import some variables from one file to another but I still can't find the correct way to do it.

The variables I want to import are these:

```
introduce_product
enter_price
enter_brand
```

This is the code of the file where the variables are:

```
def button_agree (self):
     introduce_product = self.Inp_product_name.text ()
     enter_price = self.Inp_price_name.text ()
     enter_brand = self.Inp_brand_name.text ()
```

Does anyone know how to import them correctly into a file?
Thanks if you answer!

Comment: `from filename import variables_you_need` or `*`

Comment: Ok, but it throws me this import error:
ImportError: Unable to import name 'introduce_product' from 'prefix' (C: \ Users \ brand \ Desktop \ program \ prefix.py)      :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have two .py files in the same directory, say

- main.py
- var.py

var.py:

```
variable = 23
```

main.py:

```
import var
print(var.variable)
```

output:

```
23
```

If you're having errors with this, also try to create an empty python file named
_*init*_.py